# Text in Textarea is writing under the placeholder tex

Tags: html, css, wkhtmltopdf

My goal is to have a PDF report generated from a HTML file using wkHTMLtoPDF.
In my HTML file, I have to add a `textarea`. So, I write:

```
<form>
    <textarea name= "Conclusion" id="textarea" placeholder="Some text..."></textarea>
</form>
```

In the PDF generated, when I enter a message in the `textarea`, text of placeholder won't be cleared and the new text is writing under it.

Comment: Explain what you've tried and show some relevant code.

Comment: I try to add an editable area in a PDF document using HTML file.
I add correctly textarea with a placeholder text in HTML file. But when i generate the PDF doc and try to edit textarea, placeholder text is still there and my new message is writing under it.